# 500 Server Error on underscore js template tag

Tags: javascript, php, apache, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

I've been using underscore js template inside zend framework's phtml file and they are working fine locally but on my production server. It giving me 500 internal server for all the underscore template tags <% %>

```
<script id="viewRegTemplate" type="text/underscore">
    <select name="manager" id="manager">
    <% _.each(managers, function(manager){ %>
        <option value="<%= manager.id %>"><%= manager.user_name %></option>
    <% }); %>
    </select>
</script>
```

is not recognizing as underscore js template and reading as PHP?? Please help...

On server error log I found this PHP Fatal error...

PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/application/views/scripts/myportal/default.phtml on line 75

Comment: php short tag in php config check? php versions check?

Comment: I just checked php version is 5.3 and short tag is on

Comment: is your sever allow to check/remove phtml handler in apache config

Comment: I don't think so man I am using iPage..

Comment: uhh damn found the culprit!!
; Allow ASP-style <% %> tags.
; http://php.net/asp-tags
asp_tags = On

Comment: yea, i remember is something tag like setting